# Headless browser library for these programming languages

Tags: c++, c, go, d, headless-browser

HtmlUnit is an headless browser library based on Java. Is there an headless browser library for the C/C++, D and Go programming language?

Comment: Is invoking Java from C acceptable for you?

Comment: That's 4 questions, not one.

Comment: @cubic Technically it could still be one question (a library that supports all 4 languages).

Comment: my dom.d is one component that may help read html in D. get it here: https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you [Go](https://github.com/mattn/go-webkit/blob/master/example/webview.go).

(Dummy text to make it at least 30 characters long)

Comment: Instead of a dummy text you could have written the libraries name, where it is hosted, what browser engine it uses, …

Answer (score 0):

How about **Gowut**?

> Gowut (Go Web UI Toolkit) is a full-featured, easy to use, platform
>   independent Web UI Toolkit written in pure Go, no platform dependent
>   native code is linked or called.

[Gowut Home page](https://sites.google.com/site/gowebuitoolkit/)

[Gowut Project page](http://code.google.com/p/gowut/) (it's open source)

**Edit:** Checking out what HtmlUnit is, Gowut is not exactly the same for Go...